# React composite components cause linting error in mdxjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mdxjs

I am writing some documentation in .mdx (mdxjs) using [Storybook js](https://storybook.js.org/) for a React composite component.

When I import the component into the mdx file and try to reference the composite child the linter (`"eslint-plugin-mdx": "^2.0.5"`) complains it is undefined - but the output in Storybook does work as expected.

```
### CompositeComponent

Some copy about the component.

<Canvas isExpanded={true}>
  <>
    <GlobalStyle />
    <CompositeComponent>
      <CompositeComponent.Child>item</CompositeComponent.Child>
      <CompositeComponent.Child>item</CompositeComponent.Child>
    </CompositeComponent>
  </>
</Canvas>
```

Obviously I can turn off the rule for the this file but I would ideally like it to work or at least understand why it does not.